# Django model query for non appartenance in a list

Tags: django, model

I am trying to query a Django model for the non appartenance in a list. 
For exemple `MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=[])` is permitted, but what I need is the opposite operation. Something like `pk__not_in=some_model_list`. Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
MyModel.objects.exclude(pk__in=[])
```